# how to load and re-use kereas model between requests using uwsgi and flask?

Tags: nginx, flask, uwsgi, flask-restful

I have a rest API run using uwsgi and flask.

I load a Kereas model every request and hence the response is slow. How can I load the model once and re-use it across requests

Comment: What is that your are loading?

Comment: A trained kereas CNN model...